# using a template whose controllers are different from calling page

Tags: visualforce

I was trying to use `apex:composition` and refer to a template page with a different controller compared to page i am calling template from.

Does this follow same execution order defined at 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_get_request.htm

if I alter

second `step:custom` components on page? to custom components,composition,include on page?
and third step to : evaluate constructors+expressions on attribute on custom components and
constructors + action methods on composition/include(if any)

I tried with below code and can see this is what is happening
Template:page

```
<apex:page controller="composcontroller" action="{!URLFOR($action.account.list,$objecttype.Account)}">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputLabel for="Name">Enter your name</apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText value="{!name}" id="Name"/>
        <apex:insert name="age"></apex:insert>
        <apex:insert name="meal"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Template constructor:

```
public class composcontroller {
    string name;

    public  composcontroller() {        
        system.debug('composcontroller');        
    }

    public pagereference save() {        
        return null;
    }   

    public string getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(string a) {
        name = a;
    }
}
```

Calling page:

```
<apex:page controller="composcontroller2"  >
    <apex:composition template="compocontro">

        <apex:define name="age">
            <br/>
            <apex:outputLabel for="Age"> Enter your age</apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:inputText value="{!age}" id="Age"/>
        </apex:define>

        <apex:define name="meal">            
            <apex:outputLabel for="meal">Enter meal</apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:inputtext value="{!meal}" id="meal"/>
        </apex:define>

    </apex:composition>
    <apex:outputText id="greeting"  value="Hello 
                                           Would you like some delicious {!meal}?"/>
</apex:page>
```

Calling constructor:

```
public class composcontroller2 {
    public string age{get;set;}
    public string meal{get;set;}    
}
```

when you load page 2,you can see action method on template is being called and it gets redirected to standard account list page

*This is just for academic self study.I don't know whether there are use cases in real life where template and calling page has different constructors?

Comment: Are you asking what order the constructors are called?